# How to create a FileHandler using a configuration file?

Tags: java, logging, properties, configuration

1. When creating a Logger after calling LogManager.readConfiguration(InputStream), do we have to create and add a FileHandler to the Logger or will the Logger creates its own FileHandler using the configuration file below?
2. When I create a FileHandler after calling LogManager.readConfiguration(InputStream), it doesn't seem to use the properties in the configuration file (show below). Why is that?
3. Is there a way to indicate (within the configuration file) the specific FileHandler configurations that a specific named Logger would use? Ex. If I was creating a Logger named "a.bb.ccc" and I want it to use a FileHandler that has a certain limit and formatter, but I want the default FileHandler to use some other limit and formatter, how would I do that?

   ```
   handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler

   .level = ALL

   # Default
   java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = FINEST
   java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = package1.package2.package3.SimpleFormatter
   java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 10000
   java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 7
   java.util.logging.FileHandler.append = true

   # package1.package2.class1
   package1.package2.class1.level = FINER
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Read configuration creates the FileHandler.  You don't have to add one.
2. 'package1.package2.package3.SimpleFormatter' has to be public, visible to the system class loader, with a public no arg constructor, and no exceptions have escaped the constructor in order for it to be installed.
3. It is not supported using the properties syntax but you can use the [config](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#LogManager--) option described in the LogManager class level documentation instead.  Create a new class 'package.SimpleFileConfig' and have the default constructor set everything the way you want it.  Then your logging.properties will contain one line: `config=package.SimpleFileConfig`

Comment: 1. Based on what you said, it automatically will create one. Is is because of "handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler"? 2. It doesn't work because I am not using the default formatter? Why can't I used my custom formatter? 3. I thought the properties file would make things more flexible during runtime, but I guess not.

Comment: 1. Correct.  2. Will work as long as your class is accessable from the system classloader, is public, and has a public no-arg constructor.